# Weird ServiceStack request DTO naming bug (v 3.9.71)

Tags: servicestack

We were using ServiceStack 3.9.42 one of our apps. It was working very well but we decided to upgrade to ServiceStack version 3.9.71.

After upgrading ServiceStack, there were 3 services missing in metadata; the request dto names are:

UpdateBookingStatusId
GetIncomingBookings
IsAuthenticated

If I change their names (ex: IsAuthenticated -> CheckUserSession) I can see them in metadata. Am I missing something about naming request DTOs in ServiceStack?
Anyone hit the same issue with me?

Comment: Are you using standard resolution of routes? Please provide your routes configuration, service and dtos in order to be able to think about the problem.